# Application calls onPause() when I'm calling super.finish()

Tags: android, handler, onpause

I have this code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Config.SPLASH_ENABLED)
    {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        doLogin();
    }
}
```

So when I push Back button it closed the first activity but then starts second one so I can start this app more than 1 in same time. Then I decide to override `onBackPressed()` method.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);   
        super.finish();
    }
```

It didn't help. After Overriding `onPause()` method like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

it worked, But I really can't understand. Why it works after overriding `onPause()` method??

Answer (score 0):

Is the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

When you call to finish internally call onPause, onStop  and onDestroy; is simplier than define calls for every combination of states.

Comment: But if I call removeCallbacks() for handler in onBackPressed() then why it starts second activity?

Comment: how much is SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH? maybe is to small and sometimes you can press back key before the action of the thread is executed.

Comment: It's equal to 1500 milliseconds. Is it okay?

Comment: Better try big; try with 15000 milliseconds.

Comment: At least for discard this posibility

Comment: I tried for 15000, but it's not work, I mean it opens second screen again without overriding onPause().

Comment: Well, i must recognize that i am lost too; the only strange that i see in your code is call super.finish() in onBackPressed instead of super.onBackPressed() but i think that is not a real problem.
Maybe you could check the return of removeCallbacks for any clue.